# Highlighting js-code inside php file

Tags: syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

I have a file `script.js.php`. It contains `PHP` and `JavaScript` code(the `js` depends on the `php`). And it is to be included into a page as js-file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js.php"></script>
```

Example of script.js.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'functions.php'
?>
var vars = {
    var1: 'value1',
    var2: 'value2',
    var2: '<?php echo phpFunction(); ?>'
}
```

Does anybody know, is it possible to make `PhpStorm` higlight JavaScript code within a PHP file without using `script`-tag?

Maybe there is some kind of pseudo-tags which wouldn't affect final html/js but make PhpStorm hightlight code "properly", e.g.

```
<!-- <section language="javascript">--> 
    js goes here 
<!-- </section> -->
```

Comment: **Settings | Template Data Languages** -- find your file(s)/folder(s) and assign `JavaScript` to them (instead of default HTML).

Comment: @LazyOne. Awesome! Thx. Put this in answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Settings | Template Data Languages** -- find your file(s) or folder(s) and assign `JavaScript` to them (instead of default HTML).

If you keep your stuff well organized, then you will benefit from keeping all `*.js.php` files under separate subfolder -- this allows single assignment for a whole folder (and all files inside) instead of multiple assignments for individual files.

Comment: Note that this is a far better solution than adding, say, *.js.php to File Types because then it doesn't inject libraries for some reason. It'll say `window` is undefined and `jQuery` is undefined. This way though, with Template Data Languages, you still get code completion with libraries like jQuery or even just DOM like the `window` object.

Answer (score 8):

- Put your cursor on the JavaScript part
- Press `Alt + Enter`
- Select `Inject Language`
- Select `JavaScript`

For example:

```
<?php
echo "<script>/* CURSOR HERE*/
    alert('Hello World');
    </script>";
```

Comment: That's different -- he has different approach -- no `echo` is used, as you can see, so there is no place for manual language injection

Comment: thx, but it forbidden to use `<script>` tag within js file. as far as I know.

Comment: @LazyOne then there is no such way. He should either put his *.php in the settings to be highlighted as .js files, or he should put his script as a string so he can use this method.

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan It was just a string example. It doesn't matter what is inside the string. You can highlight every string as any syntax.

Comment: @Jelmer this won't work for me because I don't want to call php functions inside strings.

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan So I understood by ready the comment of LazyOne on your OP. I hope it will help someone else though, or maybe you in the future :) Have fun coding

Comment: @Jelmer: yep, your unswer is helpful as well. thank you. have fun coding too.

Comment: Great way to set the parser, I struggled many times and it would have been so easy.
+1, even if the answer does not fit to this particular question

Answer (score 2):

If you use the hard-coded "JS" heredoc, it'll know it's Javascript and give you autocomplete for that snippet:

```
$javascript_code = <<<JS
  function test(){
  console.log('hello!');    
}
JS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPDocs

Directly above of the String that contains the Javascript code write:

```
/* @lang JavaScript */
```

PHPStorm will automaticly highlight the Javascript code in your PHP-String.

You can Also write

```
/* @lang MySQL */ 
/* @lang CSS */
```

to highlight CSS or MySQL Code within your PHP Code within PHPStorm