# What's a good IDE that will recognize Javascript inside PHP echo / print statement?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ide, echo

I've been looking for a good PHP IDE that would see the JavaScript / html inside echo statements, and show it as code (with all the nice colours etc.).

I have tried Komodo, Netbeans, and others. All of them show echo statements as just strings (single color).

PHP Designer 2007, is the only one that will allow me to switch languages, so I can read JS inside echo comfortably, but it has very limited features.

Comment: This will be overload if you want to format your code in every language... Consider separating javascript, html, css and php

Comment: Ok. I forget why I didn't do, as you said, in the first place. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phpstorm does this quite nicely, you can choose to 'inject' code highlighting into a php string. So for example you might have SQL as a string or JavaScript or CSS as a string. You can inject syntax highlighting into it.

This is a minor feature of PHPstorm, I have to say it is one of the greatest and more powerful IDE's available at the moment.

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/

Comment: Awesome, thanks. 

Also, found the instruction on how to do it... 
"Put your cursor on the JavaScript part
Press Alt + Enter
Select Inject Language
Select JavaScript" (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781037/highlighting-js-code-inside-php-file)

Comment: PHPStorm is really amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lot of small javascript `echo's` in your code? If it's a big chunk of code, you could put the javascript in a separate `.js` file and use PHP to echo that file:

```
$strFile = file_get_contents("/js/myjavascript.js");
if ($strFile) {
    echo $strFile;
} else {
    echo "alert('Could not load javascript.');";
}
```

This approach also keeps your code 'clean' by not mixing up several languages (and server-/client-side code) in one file.

I can imagine that it would be quite a disco in your IDE when it applies different code highlighting for different languages in one file. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use something like that:

```
echo "function foo()  
{ 
    var temp; ... 
}";
```

Strings are Strings and are treated like that. 
A workaround would be this:

```
PHP Code..
?>
function foo()
{
    var temp; ...
}
<?PHP
PHP Code...
```

Writing your stuff outside of PHP tags results in an echo.

Comment: ... And results in unreadable, clunky code.

Comment: I think the code is already unreadable and clunky ;)
It is just an answer on his question

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with Bondye's comment. I personally use Netbeans, they cater for most languages. If you separate your code, like maybe instead of writing your Javascript inline into the PHP echo, try to instead call a Javascript function, which is included in a seperate javascript file or written outside of PHP in script tags. Netbeans, in my case, will pick it up either way and make things a lot easier to debug.

Hope it helps, good luck :)

Comment: I know most people just love Netbeans, but it takes forever to start on my core 2duo (3MB memory) laptop.bloatware?