# Highlighting PHP-Code in CSS

Tags: syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

How can I enable recognizing and highlighting of PHP-code in CSS files in PhpStorm?

The files are named `*.css` and not `*.php`. I cannot change them (restriction/dependency on the environment/framework).

I'm aware of the possibilities of [Highlighting js-code inside php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781037/highlighting-js-code-inside-php-file), but this requires the extension to be `php` which isn't possible.

Comment: So ... change extension to complex one: `*.php.css` and register to `PHP files` in `Settings | File Types`; then -- as described in that link for js files. PhpStorm **has to recognize such files as PHP ones** in order to have PHP highlighting, and the only way of doing this is to assign **some pattern** to "PHP files" (can be file extension(s), can be full file name etc)

Answer (score 4):

Just assign CSS extension to php file type and then set the "outer" language to CSS at Settings/Template Language for all those files.

Comment: +1 also, if you don't want to have *all* .css files to be treated as PHP, but be more specific; the file patterns in PhpStorm accept wild cards, for example `myprefix-*.css` will probably work as well